# Symfony2 returning blank page after adding new route

Tags: php, linux, apache, symfony

just started doing some symfony. The root URL i.e. /, works fine and the index/home page is returned well with all the contents. However, I just added a new route i.e. /contact, with it's required controller. When I try to get theis new contact page on a browser, I just get an empty page yet it returns a 200 response code, meaning the request was successful. Quite confusing for me. What could be the problem? Not much code for now since I got no logic but here's my controller:

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/contact")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function contactAction()
    {
        return array(
                // ...
            );    }

}
```

Comment: we could need some of your code.

Comment: I just edited my question with some bit of code...

Answer (score 1):

If you load the page from app_dev.php, for example http://yourdomain.net/app_dev.php/contact, in log you can check which controller is called, and then you can debug from there the response.

Comment: OK, from the log I guess the correct controller is called. Here is a line from the log -- [2014-09-08 12:35:32] request.INFO: Matched route "himaya_core_contact_contact" (parameters: "_controller": "Himaya\CoreBundle\Controller\ContactController::contactAction", "_route": "himaya_core_contact_contact") [] []

Comment: ok, the controller is right. So maybe you don't want to return an array but render a template in twig?

Comment: Yap that's true...got a template in twig